# Target Desktops or Target Mobile with Queries?

Tags: ios, css

Currently doing the simple parallax effect of `background-attachment: fixed` and `background-size: cover` only to realize that iOS does not want to play nice at all with `background-attachment: fixed` At this point given the repaint costs as well, I want mobile/tablet to not have `background-attachment: fixed` at all.

Which would be better, remove `background-attachment: fixed` from mobile or add it back in for desktop. Further more, which would be easier from a media query stand point. Repeating the same css over and over for different devices sounds like a bad time.

Also, trying to avoid JS as much as possible to maintain as much compatibility as I can with office computers who may have it disabled.

Comment: I find (and a lot of people) that media queries work best mobile first. So do your mobile style, then use background fixed on your desktop media queries.

Comment: @ShanRobertson the question then is what is good query and break point for desktop/laptop? A Surface 3 can run it no problem but we are not sure what the iPad Pro will be like yet.